# Output redirection inside/outside square brackets in Bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, square-bracket

Can somebody kindly clarify me if there is any difference concerning redirection between:

```
[ $var1 -eq $var2 ] &> out.tmp
```

and

```
[ $var1 -eq $var2 &> out.tmp ]
```

This is, redirecting outside vs. inside square brackets. I googled for an answer with no luck. In Bash, both seem to work the same.

Thank you!

PS: using double square brackets would make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash manual says "*... redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.*" `[` ... `]` is a simple command (you can look up the definition in the bash manual), so the redirection may appear anywhere. `[[` ... `]]` is listed as a compound command, so redirection may only follow it.

Comment: If redirection may only follow a `[[`...`]]`, how do you redirect inside the test? For example, if I don't care about the `stderr` of the command(s) that is being tested, but only about the `stderr` of the test itself, how do I redirect the command's `stderr` to `/dev/null` so I don't see it? For example, how do I do this: `[[ $(rm folder; ls folder) -ne 0 ]]` if the folder has no files to begin with (and so `rm` will throw an error on `stderr`)? This is only an example, and not something I recommend running.

Comment: We can still put `2>/dev/null` after the `]]`, since the redirection also applies inside, and `[[` per se doesn't output anything (a syntax error would be reported by bash unredirected). Also we can put redirections inside the `$(…)`, e. g. `[[ $(rm folder 2>/dev/null; ls folder 2>/dev/null) -ne 0 ]]` or `[[ $((rm folder; ls folder) 2>/dev/null) -ne 0 ]]`.